# drawing highlight component on top of delegate in GridView

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2

I am trying to force highlight item to be drawn over currently selected item in GridView without any success.
Here is my QML:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

GridView {
    id: gridView
    width: 140
    height: 140
    cellHeight: 70
    cellWidth: 70

    highlight: Rectangle {
        color: "red"
        z: 1
    }

    delegate: Item {
        id: itemId

        width:  GridView.view.cellWidth
        height: GridView.view.cellHeight

        Text {
            id: textId
            text: "1234"
        }

        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked: itemId.GridView.view.currentIndex = index
        }
    }

    model: 100
}
```

I was hoping setting `z` to 1 for highlight component will do the job but that's not working as expected. If I select items which show just after window is open, my highlight covers them, but when I start scrolling, and selecting items below, highlight is no longer on top. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default value for `z` in `GridView` delegate is 1 ([link](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-gridview.html#delegate-prop)). Don't know why it's impossible to specify property `z: 0` (then it's always back to default) when it's possible to set any other value than 0. But you can specify `z: 2` in highlight property, or overwrite default `z` to 0 in delegate's `onCompleted` handler:

```
Component.onCompleted: {
    z = 0;
}
```